# How to delete on based of subkey using hset in redis in node js app

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am trying to use `redis` in my `nodejs` application. I am able to save and retrieve value perfectly. I am using hash which allows me to have single unique key as well sub-keys. Here offer id is my sub key and offer is key.

I am saving offer like below

```
let offer = {
    offerId: req.query.id,
    offerName: req.query.offerName,
    offerVendor: req.query.offerVendor
}
client.hset('offer', offer.offerId, JSON.stringify(offer), redis.print);
```

and retrieving value like below

```
try {   
    console.log('ping response:', await client.ping());
    const offerId = req.query.id;
    client.hget('offer', offerId, function(err, reply){
        let offer = JSON.parse(reply);
        res.send(offer);
    });
} catch(err) {
    console.log('ping error:', err);
}
```

I want to delete offer based on id as like saving or getting on based of id. I have gone through documentation https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#usage-example but didn't find there.

What is the way to do delete offer based on id ?

Comment: We can use"del" and see the below link for reference

https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/master/test/commands/del.spec.js

Comment: @Hemanth I think it will delete complete offer key, do you have any idea how to delete on based of sub key ? in my case offer id

Comment: don't have any idea, but I would suggest to restore by removing sub key by using underscore/lodash and store it again into redis .

Comment: @Hemanth Nah it may be inefficient approach

Comment: yeah... I know that its inefficient approach, ask redis people directly in the git hub. mean time you can move with temporary fix.

try like this 
```
client.del('offer', offerId, function(err, reply){
        
    });
```

Comment: @Hemanth I tried ``` client.del('offer', offerId, function(err, reply){ }); ``` it is deleting complete store, not based on sub key

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you already have the offer id, you can delete it from the offer hash using the [hdel](http://redis.io/commands/hdel) command. Your code would look something like:

```
client.hdel('offer', id)
```

The result from the call will be an integer count of the number of keys deleted.  If you don't know the client id, you can look for it using the [hscan](http://redis.io/commands/hscan) command.